# 100% width background image top cut off

Tags: html, web, css

When I use the following with a 1920x1080 pic (or for other resolutions I've tried), the very top of the picture gets cut off. Is there any way to prevent this?

```
div.background {
    background-image: url("/images/home.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: absolute; 
    height: 100%; 
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 100px;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 0;
    background-position: 50% 50%; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover; 
    -moz-background-size: cover; 
    -o-background-size: cover; 
    background-size: cover;
}

div.header {
    background-color: red;
    width:100%;
    height: 100;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;

}

body {
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}

<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main2.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="header"></div>
<div class="background"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

That's what `background-size: cover` does, makes it so that your background image is scaled, while maintaining aspect ratio, to cover the entirety of its container. If the aspect ratio of the image and the `div` do not match, you get clipping.

If you can guarantee that your background image will always have the same aspect ratio, you could do something like this:

```
div.background {
    background-image: url("/images/home.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: absolute; 

    /* these lines are the important bits */
    height: 0;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    box-sizing: border-box;

    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 100px;
    top: 0;
    /* bottom: 0; */
    left: 0;
    /* right: 0; */
    z-index: 0;
    background-position: 50% 50%; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover; 
    -moz-background-size: cover; 
    -o-background-size: cover; 
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Relative padding and margins are all based on `width`, not `height`. Using that specific percentage causes the `div` to have an aspect ratio matching the image, 16:9. Having the same aspect ratio means that no clipping will occur when using `cover`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10441480/367865) on the topic.

`border-box` causes the `height` and `width` to include the `padding` and `border` sizes but not `margin` size, preventing `margin` from effecting the `div`'s dimensions.

Comment: Woah! Complicated response, I'll have to weed through it, but this is totally it. Thank you :-)

Answer (score 1):

change the margin-top on your div.background to 0px. That will remove the cut off from the picture

```
div.background {
background-image: url("/images/home.jpg");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
position: absolute; 
height: 100%; 
width: 100%;
margin-top: 0px;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
z-index: 0;
background-position: 50% 50%; 
-webkit-background-size: cover; 
-moz-background-size: cover; 
-o-background-size: cover; 
background-size: cover;
```

}

Comment: This covers up the header